# Ethernet card not detected on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, networking, server, ethernet

My onboard ethernet isn't detected after a re-install of Server 12.04.  For reasons I won't get into here, I had to put the server's drive into another machine to install Ubuntu, then swap back into the server.

So the server starts up fine, except for the "Waiting for network configuration".

I read in another article that Server, by default, doesn't handle new mac addresses for hardware changes dynamically, unlike Ubuntu Desktop, but a look at /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules shows only one ethernet interface.  Shouldn't it show both the old, and the new?

lspci -vv shows an ethernet interface, so what the heck is going on?

I should mention that the onboard LAN is enabled in the BIOS.

And I know this isn't important, but all this started when I changed some network configuration settings in webmin before the re-install.  It couldn't download any updates, so I tinkered a little.  Broke, it, installed FreeNAS, which worked, but I didn't like it, then went back to Ubuntu Server, and now I'm in this pickle.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Ok, so the ethernet works when in recovery mode.  I actually managed to download, install, and access ajenti.  Figured all was well, so I restarted, and got the same "Waiting on network configuration"...

Answer (score 2):

looking at

/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:02:08.0 (e100)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:07:e9:3c:34:1f", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:02:01.0 (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:07:e9:3c:34:1f", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Which says my new network card is eth1 - but it did not work as eth1, so i commented out everything, and then after reboot, udev found my new card as eth0

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:02:08.0 (e100)
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:07:e9:3c:34:1f", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:02:01.0 (e1000)
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:07:e9:3c:34:1f", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:02:01.0 (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:07:e9:3c:34:1f", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

ifconfig:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:e9:3c:34:1f  
          inet addr:192.168.0.16  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::207:e9ff:fe3c:341f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16698 (16.6 KB)  TX bytes:14257 (14.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:440 (440.0 B)  TX bytes:440 (440.0 B)
```

my net config file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.16
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.4
```

everything works here now - system is happy

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't tried that machine in a while since I gave up on it, but I'll try this fix and get back to you.